# How to make Iterator subclass methods observe array pointer functions?

Tags: php

The standard `current` `key` and `next` functions seem to ignore Iterator subclass methods.

In this example I just override the `Iterator::current` method to return a modified string. It seems that my method has a different state to the parent class. It doesn't have access to the same pointer, and it doesn't fire when `current()` is called on an instance.

```
<?php

class DecoratingIterator extends ArrayIterator {

    public function current(){
        return '**'.strtoupper( parent::current() ).'**';
    }
}

$test = new DecoratingIterator( ['foo','bar'] );

next($test);

echo $test->current(),"\n"; 
// prints "**FOO**"

echo current($test),"\n";   
// prints "bar"
```

I'm sure this is expected behaviour, but is there a way to make my subclass methods work when the PHP functions are called on it?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think `next()` and its friends do not use the methods of interface `Iterator` at all. They modify the internal pointer of the array while an iterator is an external class that keeps itself the status of the iteration (over an array or other data structure). Compare the documentation of function [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) with documentation of method [`Iterator::next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.next.php). The iterators are designed to work with `foreach` while the old functions `current()`, `next()` have a different way of work.

Comment: A good read on that : https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html

Comment: @axiac next and friends do work with native iterators like ArrayIterator, but you're right that they work differently and should never be called on custom objects it seems. It's the subclass quirk that had me confused. I put a little Gist up to show: https://gist.github.com/timwhitlock/d791a357520f73b4d2f9

Answer (score 1):

This answer requires the [APD functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) to be installed.

The reason for this is `current`, `key` and `next` aren't part of `ArrayIterator`, and even if they were you would still be calling `ArrayIterator::current()`, which runs the original method in `ArrayIterator`. What you need to do is overwrite the function `current` and instruct it to call your new function using [`override_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php). Something like this should do it (**NB:** I've not tested this).

```
rename_function('current', 'original_current');
override_function('current', '$obj', 'return override_current($obj);');
function override_current($obj)
{
    if ($obj instanceof DecoratingIterator)
    {
        return $obj->current();
    }
    else
    {
        return original_current($obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: And `override_funtion` is availabe how? Is it a default function of PHP? Installation required through PECL?

Comment: @dbf as I mentioned in my answer you need the APD functions.

Comment: Interesting answer, thank you. I'm not keen to mess with internal PHP functions, but I suppose I did ask how to *make* PHP do something it's obviously not supposed to :) I'll accept the answer if nothing more pragmatic is forthcoming.